# Rds_instance failing to create RDS databases inside Aurora Cluster using Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I am trying to create an Aurora DB cluster with 1 writer / reader node.

It does not appear that Ansible currently supports Cluster creation for Aurora, so I am creating this using the AWS CLI.

```
#NOTE - Currently, Ansible does not support creating an RDS cluster in the official documentation.  This may change in the future.
- name: Create the DB cluster
  command: >
    aws rds create-db-cluster
      --db-cluster-identifier production-db
      --engine aurora-mysql
      --db-subnet-group-name webserver-connections
      --vpc-security-group-ids sg-dja17283
      --storage-encrypted
      --db-cluster-parameter-group-name my-parameter-group
      --master-username "my_username"
      --master-user-password "My_Password"
      --backup-retention-period 7
  when: aurora_cluster == ''


- name: Create instances inside of cluster
  rds_instance:
    engine: aurora
    engine_version: "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.2"
    db_instance_identifier: ansible-test-aurora-db-instance
    instance_type: db.t2.small
    cluster_id: production-db
    multi_az: yes
    storage_encrypted: yes
   # backup_retention_period: 7
    tags:
      Environment: "Production"
```

This returns -

```
"msg": "Unable to create DB instance: An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the CreateDBInstance operation: Cannot find version 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.2 for aurora",
```

If I set the engine to be `aurora-mysql`, I see the following -

```
"msg": "Unable to create DB instance: An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the CreateDBInstance operation: VPC Multi-AZ DB Instances are not available for engine: aurora-mysql"
```

When uncommenting backup retention period (it is defined both in the initial cluster creation CLI call, as well as the play), I see the following -

```
"msg": "Unable to create DB instance: An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the CreateDBInstance operation: The requested DB Instance will be a member of a DB Cluster. Set backup retention period for the DB Cluster.
```

Is it possible to use Ansible to create an Aurora-Mysql Multi-AZ RDS cluster?  From reading the documentation, it doesn't appear to be supported yet.

Is it possible to use Ansible to manage the DB instances inside of a cluster, such as the reader / writer nodes in a multi-az aurora-mysql deployment?  If so, how can I do this?  All of my testing has returned similar results as above.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason for choosing Ansible over Terraform?

Comment: My team lead hates Terraform, and is not willing to use it (he feels strongly about this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if Ansible supports Aurora yet or not, but all those error messages are valid.

You need to change `engine` to `aurora-mysql`, and remove `multi-az` or set it to `false` since `multi-az` is not an available Aurora feature.

Multi-az creates a 2nd "backup" instance of an RDS server in another availability zone. Since Aurora is a cluster instead of a single instance system, you would just create a second instance yourself instead of specifying `multi-az`.

Comment: Thanks.  In our other RDS clusters, we have Multi-AZ turned on.  From reading through the AWS docs, is that option set when creating the cluster using the `--availability-zones <zone1 zone2>` arguments?

Comment: I guess that's one way to look at it, yes. You are required to configure more than one availability zone, so in a sense all Aurora clusters are multi-az. However, to get the same instant failover behavior you get from an RDS multi-az setup, you need to make sure you have at least 2 instances in the Aurora cluster.